# jsonmodel deserialize object

Tags: objective-c, json, json-deserialization, jsonmodel

I'm using jsonmodel for serializing operations. I send post to server and get json data. I deserialize the data to this object.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"
@interface ResultObject : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject<Optional> *Data;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ResultCode;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ResultMessage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject<Optional> *Exception;
@end
```

I can get simple data. Like a boolean value or a string. But when i try to cast Data to my custom object. the data were corrupted. 
I'm using this code to cast.

```
ResultObject *resultObject = [[ResultObject alloc]initWithString:result error:&error];
NSString *returnAnswer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",resultObject.Data];
LanguagePack *pack =[[LanguagePack alloc]initWithString:returnAnswer usingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

the colons(:) change to equals(=)
and the comas(,) change to semicolons(;) in the returnAnswer so "pack" is null. I can't deserialize the json data.

this is my LanguagePack

```
@interface LanguagePack : JSONModel
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray<LanguageString> *Data;
@end
```

and this is my LanguageString

```
@protocol LanguageString;

@interface LanguageString : JSONModel

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataKey;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataValue;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataDescription;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataLanguage;
    @end
```

My question is that how can i deserialize the json data inside the NSObject(Data) to my custom Objects?

Edit Note: when i look at ResultObject.Data it has 14 objects(as should be) but every object has an error:

expected ']'error: 1 errors parsing expression

like this.

and if i change `NSObject<Optional> *Data` to `NSArray<LanguageString> *Data` it works properly. But i need a generic type like NSObject.

My Json

```
{
"Data":[
{
"DataKey":"AppTemplate.CancelButton.Text",
"DataValue":"Iptal",
"DataDescription":"",
"DataLanguage":"TR"
},
{
"DataKey":"Exception.Code.07",
"DataValue":"SMS dogrulama kodu hatali ya da zaman asimina ugramis.",
"DataDescription":"SmsVerificationCodeNotVerifiedException",
"DataLanguage":"TR"
},
{
"DataKey":"Exception.Code.11",
"DataValue":"Geçersiz dil bilgisi.",
"DataDescription":"InvalidLanguageException",
"DataLanguage":"TR"
}
],
"ResultCode":"00",
"ResultMessage":"Success",
"Exception":null
}
```

Sorry for my english and thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have use JSONModel framework to find out whats going on.

Note, please use **camel case** notation in your project.

Model classes (only header files are important in this case):

**LanguageString.h**

```
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol LanguageString;

@interface LanguageString : JSONModel

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataKey;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataValue;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataDescription;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *DataLanguage;

@end
```

**LanguagePack.h**

```
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "LanguageString.h"

@interface LanguagePack : JSONModel
    @property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray<LanguageString> *Data;
@end
```

**ResultObject**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"
#import "LanguageString.h"

@interface ResultObject : JSONModel

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<LanguageString> *Data;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ResultCode;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ResultMessage;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSObject<Optional> *Exception;

@end
```

and then run:

```
    NSString *json = @"{\"Data\":[{\"DataKey\":\"AppTemplate.CancelButton.Text\",\"DataValue\":\"Iptal\",\"DataDescription\":\"\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"},{\"DataKey\":\"Exception.Code.7\",\"DataValue\":\"SMS dogrulama kodu hatali ya da zaman asimina ugramis.\",\"DataDescription\":\"SmsVerificationCodeNotVerifiedException\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"},{\"DataKey\":\"Exception.Code.11\",\"DataValue\":\"Geçersiz dil bilgisi.\",\"DataDescription\":\"InvalidLanguageException\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"}],\"ResultCode\":\"00\",\"ResultMessage\":\"Success\",\"Exception\":null}";

    ResultObject *ro = [[ResultObject alloc] initWithString:json error:nil];
    NSLog(@"ResultCode=%@, ResultMessage=%@", ro.ResultCode, ro.ResultMessage);
    for (LanguageString *ls in ro.Data) {
        NSLog(@"\n-----\nDataKey=%@\nDataValue=%@\nDataDescription=%@\nDataLanguage=%@\n-----", ls.DataKey, ls.DataValue, ls.DataDescription, ls.DataLanguage);
    }
```

RESULT:

```
2014-01-24 14:46:31.050 Test[1420:70b] ResultCode=00, ResultMessage=Success
2014-01-24 14:46:31.052 Test[1420:70b] 
-----
DataKey=AppTemplate.CancelButton.Text
DataValue=Iptal
DataDescription=
DataLanguage=TR
-----
2014-01-24 14:46:31.052 Test[1420:70b] 
-----
DataKey=Exception.Code.7
DataValue=SMS dogrulama kodu hatali ya da zaman asimina ugramis.
DataDescription=SmsVerificationCodeNotVerifiedException
DataLanguage=TR
-----
2014-01-24 14:46:31.053 Test[1420:70b] 
-----
DataKey=Exception.Code.11
DataValue=Geçersiz dil bilgisi.
DataDescription=InvalidLanguageException
DataLanguage=TR
-----
```

I hope it is what you are expecting, a ResultObject must define the type of the array, thats the only difference:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray<LanguageString> *Data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the JSON structure of your custom Objects - I can't give you clear answer without it.

At least, I can recommend for JSON a [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can just start with something like:

```
NSData *responseData; // insert your data here
NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"response :%@", response);
```

Note, instead of '(NSDictionary*)' you may use '(NSArray*)' - it depends from your data structure.

OK, so I'll give you some idea how to parse it using NSJOSONSerlization:

```
NSData* responseData = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *response = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"response :%@", response);
// Parse
NSString *resultCode = response[@"ResultCode"];
NSString *resultMessage = response[@"ResultMessage"];
NSArray *dataArr = response[@"Data"];
for (NSDictionary *item : dataArr) {
    LanguageString *ln = [LanguageString new];
    ln.dataKey = item[@"DataKey"];
    ln.dataValue = item[@"DataValue"];
    ln.dataDescription = item[@"DataDescription"];
    ln.dataLanguage = item[@"DataLanguage"];
    /* TODO: store 'ln' object in desired model */
}
```

Of course assuming, that dataStr is similar to:

```
NSString *dataStr = @"{\"Data\":[{\"DataKey\":\"AppTemplate.CancelButton.Text\",\"DataValue\":\"Iptal\",\"DataDescription\":\"\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"},{\"DataKey\":\"Exception.Code.7\",\"DataValue\":\"SMS dogrulama kodu hatali ya da zaman asimina ugramis.\",\"DataDescription\":\"SmsVerificationCodeNotVerifiedException\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"},{\"DataKey\":\"Exception.Code.11\",\"DataValue\":\"Geçersiz dil bilgisi.\",\"DataDescription\":\"InvalidLanguageException\",\"DataLanguage\":\"TR\"}],\"ResultCode\":\"00\",\"ResultMessage\":\"Success\",\"Exception\":null}";
```

Please note, this is only a hint. Also consider using such framework as [ResKit](http://restkit.org)

Comment: i add the json to question

Comment: it's not working. the same problem. the "dataStr" is correct. but the "Data" in the "response" corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The "Data" key in your JSON feed IS an array. Therefore your "Data" property also needs to be an array instead of NSObject.

But I guess you already knew that since you noted that it works if you do that

Comment: Yes my problem is getting the data as an nsobject. after it casting to the type what i need. (array or custom object or string or bool, it can be every type)

Comment: JSONModel validates the structure of your JSON before creating a model instance, you can't have ANY type for a given key